# Winapi edit control chenge selected text font color

Tags: winapi, c++builder, vcl

I have text in edit control and I want to change color to some piece of text.
In Embarcadero C++ builder, I'm selecting text like this:

```
edit1->SelStart = 10;
edit1->SelLength = 12;
```

and then change color:

```
edit1->SelAttributes->Color = clRed;
```

It's posible in Winapi standard Edit control or I must use Rich edit?

Comment: TEdit does not have a SelAttributes property. TRichEdit does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer. No, you have to use a Rich Edit Control. Here a link to all messages a editcontrol can process: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A standard Edit control does not support per-character text formatting.  You must use a RichEdit control for that.